# Ionic command is not running after updating

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I updated Cordova and Ionic using npm. The update ran without any error. But, now when I enter $ionic on the terminal, it gives this error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic:6
process.on('unhandledRejection', r => console.error(r));
                                   ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ionic but it didn't work. Could anyone show me the way?

Comment: What is your Mac OS version?

Comment: @Dar My MacBook Pro (Early 2011) is running MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally understood what was wrong.
I had updated everything; Ionic, Cordova, and npm. But what I didn't update was nodejs. After updating it, ionic started working again.